# sstable2json hangs when I try to inspect an sstable

Tags: cassandra

I have an sstable file stored at `/var/lib/cassandra/data/foo/bar/foo-bar-jb-1-Data.db`, and I tried to read the contents of this file by running the following command:

```
$ sstable2json /var/lib/cassandra/data/foo/bar/foo-bar-jb-1-Data.db
```

However, the terminal simply hangs after issuing this command, even though the file is only 4k in size. Any ideas what could be the problem? I'm using cassandra 2.0.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permissions maybe. The 2.x docs about the tool have been removed because sstable2json is deprecated. Here are the older docs: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/tools/toolsSStable2json_track_ttl_t.html

Comment: It seems like this tool has not been maintained since it was deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and running it from sudo worked for me. So it appears to be permission problem.